# Prove (A,☆) a semi-group with the following conditions is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let (A,☆) be a semi-group such that the following 2 conditions are true:

1. For any $a,b\in A$, there exists a $x\in A$ such that $a☆x=b$
2. For any $a,b\in A$, there exists a $y\in A$ such that $y☆a=b$

Note: ☆ is a binary operation on A.

Prove that (A,☆) is a group.

I know to show it is a group I have to show (A,☆) has an identity element e, and that each element has an inverse that returns the element e. I can show that the binary operation has a left and right identity by letting a=b, but then how can I show it has an identity: e? Can I assume they are equal because it is a semi-group?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have shown that $A$ has a left identity $e$ that satisfies 
$$
e \star a = a \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }\text{ }\forall a \in A \tag{i}
$$
and a right identity $e’$ satisfying
$$
b \star e’ = b \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }\text{ }\forall b \in A \tag{ii},
$$
you can show they are equal by first setting $a = e’$ in (i) and then setting $b = e$ in (ii).

Having shown that $A$ has an identity element, a proof that $A$ is closed under inverses is as follows: applying your axiom (1) for $b = e$, we conclude that for each $a$, there is an element $a’$ so that 
$$
a \star a’ = e. \tag{iii}
$$
Meanwhile, by your axiom (2), it follows that for each $a$ there is an element $a’'$ so that
$$
a'' \star a = e. \tag{iv}
$$
That is, each $a$ has a left inverse and a right inverse.
To prove that $a’ = a’’$ for each $a$, multiply (iii) by $a’’$ on the left, multiply (iv) by $a’$ on the right, and use associativity.

Answer (score 1):

Try $e_l=e_le_r=e_r$.  Thus you have $e$.

Now you have to show that you have inverses.  By assumption you have, given $g$, a left and a right inverse, $g_l^{-1},g_r^{-1}$.

Now to show they're equal.   Consider $g_l^{-1}=g_l^{-1}e=g_l^{-1}(gg_r^{-1})=(g_1^{-1}g)g_r^{-1}=eg_r^{-1}=g_r^{-1}$.